# Мерцают спрайты на стыках при передвижении камеры в 2D игре

Tags: unity3d

Дело в том, что при передвижении камеры, спрайты на стыках мерцают и можно заметить цвет фона, который стоит за спрайтами. Использую Tilemap. Pixel Per Unit стоит 32.
Ссылка на видео: https://arthyrax200015.wistia.com/medias/0mqu1wvsjc
На видео плохо видно, но в игре это сильно заметно и если присмотреться на землю, то можно заметить те самые мерцания.

Comment: Вставить ссылку на видео?

Comment: @RiotBr3aker вставил